# Add multiple dir in kafka log.dir config and create soft link for some partitions. What's the difference?

Tags: apache-kafka

Some of my servers in kafka cluster have a very high io util, so I'm trying to move some kafka partitions data dir to another disk to reduce high io util. Instead of add multi dir in log.dir config, it seems simply move some partitions dir to other disk and create soft link is much more easier. So are there differences between these two approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's feasible to spread the load across new disks by resorting to OS, creating symlinks as you mentioned for example. Kafka should be designed to be no aware of it. I mean you should be able to produce/consume any records for those partitions. However, due to a known bug ([KFAKA-7897](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7897)) topics with such symlinks could not be deleted successfully and no matter what version you are using, only the symlinks instead of the real target files will be deleted during a topic deletion.